# Trap the date taken in php

Tags: php

I want to prevent user to enter a date that is already taken and inside the database. Like if they enter a date similar to the date inside the database they will receive an alert saying "the date you chose is already taken". I have this code but it's not doing that

**DATABASE**

```
CREATE TABLE `date_tbl` (
  `date_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `time` text NOT NULL,
  `ordertype` int(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6k61Y.png)

**PHP**

```
  <?php 
       include('db.php');
       if(isset($_POST['reserve'])){
          $fdate = $_POST['datepicker'];
          $ftime = $_POST['time'];

          $fdate_array = array();
          $ftime_array = array();

          $q=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM date_tbl");

          while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
             $fdate_array[]=$row['date'];
             $ftime_array[]=$row['time'];
          }
          if(array_intersect($fdate_array, $ftime_array)){
              die ("<script>
                     alert('Date is not available! Please pick another date');
                     window.location.href='index.php';
                  </script>");
          }else{
              $insertDate=$conn->query("INSERT INTO date_tbl (date_id, date, time, ordertype, client_id) VALUES ('','$fdate','$ftime',0)");
                if(!$insertDate){
                      die('error');
                }else{
                       $setin = $conn->query('SET foreign_key_checks = 1');
                       die("<script>
                           alert('You have reserved a date.');
                           window.location.href='index.php';
                           </script>");
                }
           }
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <h5 style="font-family:Lucida Calligraphy">Date:</h5>
  <input type="text" name="datepicker" class="form-control" placeholder='Select date' id="datepicker" style="margin-left: -15px" />
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
      });
    });
  </script>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <h5 style="font-family:Lucida Calligraphy">Time:</h5>
  <select type="text" name="time" id="time" class="form-control">
          <option>Select time</option>
          <option>10:00 AM</option>
          <option>1:00 PM</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the format of `datepicker`, `time` and the equivalent fields on `date_tbl`?

Comment: @Optimae i edit it now i added my database too.

Comment: You could have the `date_tbl` field set as unique and catch any insert errors relating to the constraint violation. The problem with what you have is if 2 requests take the exact same date at the exact same time they will both probably succeed.

Comment: @LouiseM. share the schema of your date_tbl or atleast the date field format. and also my suggestion after looking at your code sample is that why dont you query the database along with the entered date in where condition something like `SELECT Count(*) from date_tbl where date = $fdate AND where time = $ftime`

Comment: Please copy the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table_name>` in the question, instead of a link to an image. Images don't tell what data type is used. The saying "A picture is worth a thousand words" is not applicable here.

Comment: Sorry about that i added them now.

Comment: I would do a check with ajax call after datepicker send the date to input, then you can have a simple select from db, if date is taken, it will show an error message. If you want to make it more solid, you can add a session check, so the picked date will be blocked for let's say 15 minutes if it's not changed from the same session to different date ..

Comment: I believe, all of you are missing the elephant in the room

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have an error in your code

let's look at your code:

```
$fdate = $_POST['datepicker'];
$ftime = $_POST['time'];
```

first you store those two values into vars

then you put all dates and times into arrays.

```
$fdate_array = array();
$ftime_array = array();

$q=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM date_tbl");
// i assume this works
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
   $fdate_array[]=$row['date'];
   $ftime_array[]=$row['time'];
}
```

now ... for the check:

```
if(array_intersect($fdate_array, $ftime_array)){
```

and here you look, if the dates and times intersect ... which hopefully they don't (because a date usually doesn't match a time).

if you just want to check for the date, that is easy:

```
if(in_array($fdate, $fdate_array)) {
   die('error message');
}
```

if you want to check date-time-combination, that's a bit harder:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($fdate_array); $i++) {
   if($fdate_array[$i] == $fdate && $ftime_array[$i] == $ftime) {
       die('error message');
   }
}
```

however, this is all really inconvenient. the clean solution would be this:

```
// assuming pdo here, if you use mysqli, check how it's done there
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM date_tbl WHERE date=:date AND time=:time');
$stmt->bindValue(':date', $fdate);
$stmt->bindValue(':time', $ftime);
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->fetchColumn()) {
    die('error message');
}
```

this will use the database to find conflicting date-time-combinations (this is *much* more efficient). use prepared statements, just fetch the count, fetchColumn fetches the count. Good luck.

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindValue() on boolean` I'm getting this error

Comment: so you don't use pdo, is that correct? why would you ignore the rest? any comment on that?

Comment: It's all good, I'm just gonna use the date-only condition since its the only one working for me right now. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

There is one major issue with the database design for `date_tbl`. The `time` column is stored as a text field. Since date and time are used together to identify a specific point in time, it would be much more efficient to store them in a column of type `datetime`. (MySQL also has a `time` type, but that is more suitable for durations.)

`Datetime` also allows you to sort items correctly. After all, you would want `8 AM` to appear before `1 PM`.

To simplify the code you would need to post the time values in 24h format. Of course your users would still want to select using a 12h format, but that is no problem:

```
<select type="text" name="time" id="time" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select time</option>
    <option value="10:00">10:00 AM</option>
    <option value="13:00">1:00 PM</option>
</select>
```

Then simply combine the `$fdate` and `$ftime` values to `$fdatetime`

```
$fdatetime = $fdate . ' ' . $ftime;
```

You can then use the `$fdatetime` value in queries (and use a query like the one Jakumi suggested to let the database do all the work).

To display dates and times, combine the functions [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)